# How to properly use useTransition in a simple application?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a simple application that retrieves data from a Redux store. The store is saved from the api via middleware.

I want to achieve that until the data from the api is loaded, I will show the status Loading ...

Where is the problem please? The console is not reporting me and the loading status is not displayed.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useTransition } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const MovieTable = () => {
  const { movieDetail } = useSelector(state => state.movieDetail);
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    startTransition(() => {
      setMovie(movieDetail);
    });
  }, [movieDetail]);

  return (
    <div>
      {isPending && <p>Loading...</p>}
      <div>{movie.Title}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieTable;
```

Thanks